# Python codes runs using idle but fails on command line?

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and I have written a script per an example in the book I am reading where it imports the urllib library. This works fine when I run it from IDLE, but if I go to the folder where the file is and run "python test.py" I get an error where it tells me that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in ?
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

I verified that I am using Python 3.1.2. Any suggestions or ideas why this fails on the command line?

My code:

```
import urllib.request
import time

price = 99.99
while price > 1.01:
    time.sleep(3)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices.html")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])

print ("Buy!")
```

Comment: put the code inside a code block for readability

Comment: i thought i did, ill edit the post

Comment: can you let us know if you have both Python 2.x and 3 installed ?

Comment: i do see both 2.4 and 3 folders installed, im using a mac version 10.4 also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urllib.request` was introduced with Python 3. It is very possible that when you run the code from the command line, you are using an older, Python 2.x binary.

Type `python --version` on the command line to see which Python is being used.

**Edit in response to Drewdin's comment**

Running the Python 3.1.2 installer for Mac OS X, I see this:

> NOTE: This package will by default not update your shell profile and will also not install files in /usr/local.  Double-click Update Shell Profile at any time to make 3.1.2 the default Python.
>
> The installer puts the applications in "Python 3.1" 
>   in your Applications folder, and the underlying machinery in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework. It can optionally place
>   links to the command-line tools in /usr/local as well,
>   by default you have to add the "bin" directory inside
>   the framework to you shell's search path.

So depending on how you installed it, you may already have links placed in `/usr/local/bin`, which will be in your path. If you chose this option at install time, all you should have to do is type `python3` or `python3.1` in your shell to get the updated version.

Otherwise, either double click that "Update Shell Profile", or add this to your path:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin`

By default, Python 3.x does not make the `python` command alias in Unix/Linux environments because it could possibly interfere with system processes/commands dependent on the default-installed Python.

Comment: using python -v it looks like the command line is using the older version. How can i change it to use the newer version? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is saying it can't find the library, so there is something different between the environments.

Here's a [tutorial on python modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) that could help.

Have a look at the PYTHONPATH environment variable:

```
 $ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

at least on a UNIX box.  (Don't recall for Windows, honestly.)

Have a look also at Python's built in path with the line

```
 print sys.path
```

Odds on are that PYTHONPATH differs between the command line and IDLE environments.

Comment: Thanks, i checked your link but i did not see how to change the command line to look at the newer version. Did i just not look hard enough?

Comment: Drewdin, in your Applications folder find the Python3.1 folder (or similar) and run the .command script in there (just double click it). It will modify your PATH for you

Comment: @Parker I clicked that script and it finished stating that im all set from here on out but it didn't work. I still need to type python3.0 instead of just python. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the display when you run 'python' in your command line?

Answer (score 0):

Either you do `from urllib import request`,

or you specify it during the call

```
import urllib
urlib.request (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drewdin, when you type 'python' in your Terminal command line, it will display the version that it's running. If it's not 3.1, which is when urllib.request was introduced, try `python3.1 test.py`

Also, try `import urllib` instead of `import urllib.request`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem while following the same example from the same book "Head First Programming"
First, I installed Python 3, as the version that ubuntu rolls with is currently Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Then, you must install the corresponding Idle:

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.2
```

press alt+F2 to bring up your run dialogue box,
type '*`idle-python3.2`*' & hit return - you'll now see your python shell reads 'Python 3.2.2' at the top of the screen!